# How to print an object

Tags: ruby, class, puts

How do you change what is printed with `puts` when an object is referenced?

Consiser the following code:

```rb
class MyClass
    attr_accessor :var
    def initialize(var)
        @var = var
    end
    # ...
end
obj = MyClass.new("content")
puts obj # Prints #<MyClass:0x0000011fce07b4a0> but I want it to print "content"
```

I imagine that there is an operator that you can overload (or something similar), but I don't know what it's called so I have no clue what to search for to find the answer.

Comment: It depends on how the printing is invoked. In your example, you are using `puts`, which invokes the method `to_s` on the object. If you had written `p obj`, it would have invoked the method `inspect` on it. This is explained in the documentation of i.e. `puts`.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! I should have thought of looking in the puts documentation... :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from the documentation of [`puts`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/IO.html#method-i-puts):

> `puts(*objects)` → `nil`
>
> Writes the given objects to the stream, which must be open for writing; returns `nil`. Writes a newline after each that does not already end with a newline sequence. [...]
>
> Treatment for each object:
>
> - String: writes the string.
> - Neither string nor array: writes `object.to_s`.
> - Array: writes each element of the array; arrays may be nested.

That means: The object you pass to `puts` is not a string, therefore, Ruby will call `to_s` on that object before outputting the string to IO. Because your object has no `to_s` method implemented, the default implementation from  [`Object#to_s`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/Object.html#method-i-to_s).

To return a customize output, just add your own `to_s` method to your class like this:

```
class MyClass
  attr_accessor :var

  def initialize(var)
    @var = var
  end

  def to_s
    var
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyClass
  attr_accessor :var
  def initialize(var)
    @var = var
  end

  def to_s
    @var
  end
end

obj = MyClass.new("content")
puts obj # Prints "content"
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick response.