# Correct implementation and use of == operator in ruby

Tags: ruby, string, operator-overloading

In continuation of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75056773/how-to-print-an-object) I also have the following question.

I have a class which has a very central instance variable called `var`. It is so central to the class that when I print an object of the class, it should just print the instance variable.

When I compare that same object with a string which matches the instance variable, I would like it to return true, but that doesn't always work in the implementation below:

```rb
class MyClass
    attr_accessor :var
    def initialize(v)
        @var = v
    end
    def to_s
        @var.to_s
    end
    def inspect
        @var.inspect
    end
    def ==(other)
        self.var == other
    end
    # ... methods to manipulate @var
end

str = "test"
obj = MyClass.new("test")

puts obj # prints the var string - great this is what i want
p obj # prints the var string - great this is what i want
puts obj==str # returns true - great this is what i want 
puts str==obj # returns false - oops! Fails since i didn't overload the == operator in String class. What to do? I don't think i want to "monkey patch" the String class.
```

I understand that it's not my overwritten == operator which is used. It's the one in the String class. What do you suggest I do to get around this? Am I going down the wrong path?

I read through the question [What's the difference between equal?, eql?, ===, and ==?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156955/whats-the-difference-between-equal-eql-and) without getting an answer to my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I understand that it's not my overwritten == operator which is used. It's the one in the String class. What do you suggest I do to get around this? Am I going down the wrong path?

Before trying anything else, have a look at the docs for [`String#==`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.1.2/String.html#method-i-3D-3D):

> If object is not an instance of `String` but responds to `to_str`, then the two strings are compared using `object.==`.

In other words: you have to implement `to_str` and return the object's string value:

```
class MyClass
  # ...

  def to_str
    @var.to_s
  end
end
```

You can also return `to_s` or use `alias to_str to_s`.

With any of the above, you'd get:

```
"test" == MyClass.new("test")
#=> true
```

Note that `to_str` should only be implemented by objects that are string-like.